# Why is this ASP.NET Core 3.1 kebab casing URL not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This example attempts to use kebab case URLs as described in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-a-parameter-transformer-to-customize-token-replacement).

The code below results in the following URL:
`https://localhost:44355/Home/Parameter%20One/Parameter%20Two`

How the URL should look (SEO friendly):
`https://localhost:44355/home/parameter-one/parameter-two`

What is the correct way to force ASP.NET Core 3.1 to use kebab case URLs?

**Startup.cs ConfigureServices**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.Add(new RouteTokenTransformerConvention(
            new SlugifyParameterTransformer()));
    });
}
```

**SlugifyParameterTransformer.cs**

```
public class SlugifyParameterTransformer : IOutboundParameterTransformer
{
    public string TransformOutbound(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) { return null; }
        return Regex.Replace(value.ToString(),
            "([a-z])([A-Z])",
            "$1-$2",
            RegexOptions.CultureInvariant,
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)).ToLowerInvariant();
    }
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" 
    asp-area="" 
    asp-controller="Home" 
    asp-action="Test"
    asp-route-param1="Parameter One"
    asp-route-param2="Parameter Two">Test</a>
</li>
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Home/{param1}/{param2}")]
public IActionResult Test()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: By the way, your question isn't about routing. These are parameter _values_ that you're talking about.

Comment: Hi @John, you're right! I have updated the question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_in_a_URI hyphen is unreserved and shouldn't need to be encoded...

Answer (score 0):

Well at the first sight this requirement looks very reasonable (and solvable) but after finishing my debugging session (with source code from `asp.net core`) lasting for more than 4 hours, I've realized that your requirement really does not make sense. Why? because the segment parts of `param1` & `param2` are where your client puts ***whatever data*** in to send. As long as they are string (as in this case). So we have 2 directions, one for link generation and one for sending request via a link.

First, suppose when generating the link, you have 2 parameters: `Parameter One` and `Parameter Two`, the link is generated as what you desire for like this `/home/parameter-one/parameter-two`. Well so now what if the client sends back that same link? The framework somehow has to convert the values back (with some support of caching) from `parameter-one` to `Parameter One` and from `parameter-two` to `Parameter Two`. That surely requires caching (so you just lookup back the keys for the original values). There is no rule to arbitrarily process user's data. Now it's even weirder if the client sends some request via a link like this `/home/pa-po--pi/Should-Maintain-Case`. You see, how will the server handle that? Suppose the lookup could not find the keys `parameter-one` and `parameter-two` cached before, now it has to process the values itself. How? Convert `pa-po--pi` to `Pa po -pi` or `pA po- pi` or `pa po-pi`? what about `Should-Maintain-Case`? We need to keep the exact letter case, how do we know what it is? Just remove all the dashes? So what if the values may contain literal dashes? So it's just too complicated.

Actually when debugging, I've realized that all the required route values are loaded from `ActionDescriptor` (some kind of metadata) which always misses other dynamic runtime route values. In other words, it contains just route values of `controller` and `action` (the other route values passed-in for the link generation are not accessible at the time the `MvcEndpointDataSource` (available in `asp.net core 2.2` - the version I debugged - there may be different type with similar role in newer verions) is initialized. This takes into account only the required route values (`area`,`controller`,`action`) to build the EndPoints. That will exclude your route parameters together with the `IParameterPolicy` of `IOutboundParameterTransformer` - which is your custom slugifying class. So later when the `EndPoints` are used for link generation, we have no `IParameterPolicy` to generate the URL the way you want. That's why the `IOutboundParameterTransformer` is not executed.

Now back to your issue, your requirement only makes sense if we just need to generate the URL and the way back is not processed (meaning all the parameters `param1` and `param2` ***are ignored***). Yes that's exactly how it should be. The data you put in for link generation is just used to generate a friendly link. That means if your link targets something requiring an id, you should include that id (this of course does not require slugifying) in your route pattern.
Just look at a question link on SO which is formatted like this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66432905/what-ever-it-is`. The id part comes after `/questions/`, after the `id` part you have a friendly name of the question title. It's for showing only and not required when user opens the question. You can enter whatever string for that part (because it's ignored), so actually you just need this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66432905` to open the question.

With that newly rephrased requirement, I would give you the following solution which I believe is just one of some possible solutions (because along the pipeline of generating a link, we have multiple points to inject and adjust the logic). Here I decide to modify the route values before they being passed along. It's simple but with that approach we have 2 separate paths: one path to generate links from tag helpers (such as `AnchorTagHelper` as used by `asp-route-...`). This uses `IHtmlGenerator` internally. The other path to generate links from `LinkGenerator` (as when you use the `LinkGenerator` or `UrlHelper` directly).

So I will define 2 custom class, one for `IHtmlGenerator` and one for `LinkGenerator` to intercept the calls and modify the route values to achieve what we want:

```
//the custom IHtmlGenerator
public class SlugifyingLinkHtmlGenerator : DefaultHtmlGenerator
{
    public SlugifyingLinkHtmlGenerator(IAntiforgery antiforgery, IOptions<MvcViewOptions> optionsAccessor, IModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory, HtmlEncoder htmlEncoder, ValidationHtmlAttributeProvider validationAttributeProvider) : base(antiforgery, optionsAccessor, metadataProvider, urlHelperFactory, htmlEncoder, validationAttributeProvider)
    {
    }
    public override TagBuilder GenerateRouteLink(ViewContext viewContext, string linkText, string routeName, string protocol, string hostName, string fragment, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return base.GenerateRouteLink(viewContext, linkText, routeName, protocol, hostName, fragment, routeValues.Slugify(), htmlAttributes);
    }
    public override TagBuilder GeneratePageLink(ViewContext viewContext, string linkText, string pageName, string pageHandler, string protocol, string hostname, string fragment, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return base.GeneratePageLink(viewContext, linkText, pageName, pageHandler, protocol, hostname, fragment, routeValues.Slugify(), htmlAttributes);
    }
    public override TagBuilder GenerateActionLink(ViewContext viewContext, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, string protocol, string hostname, string fragment, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return base.GenerateActionLink(viewContext, linkText, actionName, controllerName, protocol, hostname, fragment, routeValues.Slugify(), htmlAttributes);
    }
}

//the custom LinkGenerator
public class SlugifyingRouteLinkGenerator : LinkGenerator
{
    readonly LinkGenerator _defaultLinkGenerator;
    public SlugifyingRouteLinkGenerator(LinkGenerator linkGenerator)
    {
        _defaultLinkGenerator = linkGenerator;
    }

    public override string GetPathByAddress<TAddress>(HttpContext httpContext, TAddress address, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteValueDictionary ambientValues = null, PathString? pathBase = null, FragmentString fragment = default(FragmentString), LinkOptions options = null)
    {
        return _defaultLinkGenerator.GetPathByAddress(httpContext, address, values.Slugify(), ambientValues, pathBase, fragment, options);
    }

    public override string GetPathByAddress<TAddress>(TAddress address, RouteValueDictionary values, PathString pathBase = default(PathString), FragmentString fragment = default(FragmentString), LinkOptions options = null)
    {
        return _defaultLinkGenerator.GetPathByAddress(address, values.Slugify(), pathBase, fragment, options);
    }

    public override string GetUriByAddress<TAddress>(HttpContext httpContext, TAddress address, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteValueDictionary ambientValues = null, string scheme = null, HostString? host = null, PathString? pathBase = null, FragmentString fragment = default(FragmentString), LinkOptions options = null)
    {
        return _defaultLinkGenerator.GetUriByAddress(httpContext, address, values.Slugify(), ambientValues, scheme, host, pathBase, fragment, options);
    }

    public override string GetUriByAddress<TAddress>(TAddress address, RouteValueDictionary values, string scheme, HostString host, PathString pathBase = default(PathString), FragmentString fragment = default(FragmentString), LinkOptions options = null)
    {
        return _defaultLinkGenerator.GetUriByAddress(address, values.Slugify(), scheme, host, pathBase, fragment, options);
    }
}
```

There are some extension methods to help slugify the string values (almost like the code I write for the `SlugifyParameterTransformer`):

```
//targets string
public static class SlugifyingStringExtensions
{
    public static string Slugify(this string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) { return value; }
        return Regex.Replace(value,
               "([a-z])(\\s+)?((?(2)\\S|[A-Z]))",
               "$1-$3",
               RegexOptions.CultureInvariant,
               TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)).ToLowerInvariant();
    }
}

//targets RouteValueDictionary
public static class SlugifyingRouteValueDictionaryExtensions
{
    static readonly HashSet<string> RequiredRouteKeys = new HashSet<string> { "area","controller","action" };
    public static RouteValueDictionary Slugify(this RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
    {
        if (routeValues == null) return null;
        foreach(var routeValue in routeValues.Where(e => !RequiredRouteKeys.Contains(e.Key) && e.Value != null))
        {
            routeValues[routeValue.Key] = routeValue.Value.ToString().Slugify();
        }
        return routeValues;
    }
    public static object Slugify(this object routeValues)
    {
        var rv = routeValues as RouteValueDictionary ?? new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);
        return rv.Slugify();
    }
}
```

Now it's almost done, we need to register those to replace the default ones. I've define a set of extension methods to help use that conveniently:

```
public static class SlugifyingRouteServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddSlugifyingRouteLinkGenerator(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //find the DefaultLinkGenerator registered initially (this type is internal)
        var linkGeneratorType = services.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ServiceType == typeof(LinkGenerator));
        //remove the registration (because we will replace it later with our own custom generator)
        services.Remove(linkGeneratorType);
        //add back the registration but with a different service key
        //Our implementation will resolve the default generator from this new service key
        services.AddSingleton(linkGeneratorType.ImplementationType);
        //actually register our own custom generator
        return services.AddSingleton<LinkGenerator>(sp =>
        {
            //here we obtain the DefaultLinkGenerator
            var defaultGenerator = sp.GetRequiredService(linkGeneratorType.ImplementationType) as LinkGenerator;
            return new SlugifyingRouteLinkGenerator(defaultGenerator);
        });
    }
    public static IServiceCollection AddSlugifyingLinkHtmlGenerator(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return services.AddSingleton<IHtmlGenerator, SlugifyingLinkHtmlGenerator>();
    }
    public static IServiceCollection AddSlugifyingRouteLinkGenerators(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return services.AddSlugifyingLinkHtmlGenerator()
                       .AddSlugifyingRouteLinkGenerator()
                       .Configure<MvcOptions>(o => {
                           o.Conventions.Add(new RouteTokenTransformerConvention(new SlugifyParameterTransformer()));
                       });
    }
}
```

Now use it to register the slugifying-link feature (in `Startup.ConfigureServices`):

```
services.AddSlugifyingRouteLinkGenerators();
```

wow, maybe this is one of the longest answers I've ever given :). It was simple at first but turned out complicated and ended up with a solution only after adjusting the requirement (as I explained at the beginning).

Comment: @crayden could you be more specific, what's the result?

Comment: Using the `SlugifyParameterTransformer` you have provided results in `https://localhost:44355/Home/Parameter%20One/Parameter%20Two`

Comment: @crayden so basically it changes nothing, that's strange. The regex pattern is completely different, ok let me test it in a simple demo.

Comment: @crayden actually, I think it's even stranger that the `Parameter` is not lower-cased at all. That means the code inside is not run, could you set a breakpoint inside the slugifying code to see if it's actually run? Actually your original code should result in `https://localhost:44355/home/parameter%20one/parameter%20two` but looks like it's not even run in the first place.

Comment: @crayden I'm not so sure how it actually is on your side, but your provided result looks strange, really. The code is just basic (kind of a simple demo from Microsoft), as I said there are spaces in between making it not work as expected, now if you try other values for your parameters (such as `ParameterOne` instead of `Parameter One`), it should work. But here's the strangest thing in your provided result: ***where is the /test/***? there is no way for it to be missing from the URL like that, unless your actual attribute is `Route("Home/{param1}/{param2}")`

Comment: Yes, that is the routing attribute I was using. Is there better way? Trying to upload this simple project to Github.

Comment: @crayden this is a simple issue, first have you tried setting a break-point in the slugifying code to see if it's run? I find it strange that the URL is not lower-cased at all. That's impossible, unless the code is not run or there is some other code affecting the result URL.

Comment: I added a breakpoint, but it never hit the code. Here is the Github repo `https://github.com/andrewcrayden/slugify`.

Comment: @crayden well so that's the actual issue, with your original code and if it runs, the output will be like `https://localhost:44355/home/parameter%20one/parameter%20two` but because it does not run, the output is like what you provided. If it runs, with my code here, the output should be expected like `https://localhost:44355/home/parameter-one/parameter-two` - I'm not so sure if we can find why it's not run soon, let me think a bit.

Comment: @crayden sorry that I could not make it work on my side as well, actually I can just use `asp.net core 2.2`, however looks like it's the same. Somehow the slugifying code is not executed at all. Trying to dig into the source code is a very hard work, a lot of classes are involved, here's the point I believe is where the `TransformOutbound` is called: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Http/Routing/src/Template/TemplateBinder.cs#L511 But as you see, there are some conditions for it to be called, it's hard to track down there :(

Comment: @crayden I think you can try filing an issue on the dotnet/aspnetcore github or ask another question on SO. Really I'm happy if you share with me the link. I myself will try to track down this issue and surely will let you know if I find something new. It will take a lot of time for sure.

Comment: @crayden I've updated my answer with many things new. Really it's not simple as you think. The slugifying code works well with `area`, `controller` and `action` **but not** for other route values. Please see my update to understand more, your requirement can still be fulfilled but just for one direction: ***generate the link***.